# CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project Hello ****


(Cannot run program "make" (in directory "C:\Users\A234049\workspaceHelios\Hello"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Hello I'm trying to run a simple helloworld program using C++ in Eclipse Helios, But I get the above error when I try to run the application program.
Any help? Many thanks!
Following is my program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("Hello World!!!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You also need to find a different C++ book. The one you are using is no good.

Comment: PS While correctly resolved as a duplicate, if you are going to use Eclipse, please use a current version (Neon) or after June (Oxygen). Helios is very old - https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/